# how can I select one Element from an XML with xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey I got an Problem with an XML File.
I received some help here but after that i came to another Problem. I tried to select the first element in an XML file and copy it to another position.

this is the original:

```
<products>
     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
        </varitems>
    </product>

     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">001 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">002 (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
        </varitems>
     </product>
</products>
```

desired output:

```
<products>
     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
            <item>
              <varno>14205</varno>
              <text>text</text>

            </item>
            <item>
              <varno>14205</varno>
              <text>text</text>
            </item>
        </varitems>
    </product>

     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">001</item>
            <item name="Part No.">002</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
            <item>
              <varno>001</varno>
              <text>text</text>
            </item>
            <item>
              <varno>001</varno>
              <text>text</text>
            </item>
        </varitems>
     </product>
</products>
```

I trieb it with that

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="OrderingInfo">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <varitems></varitems>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="varitems">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::product/OrderingInfo/item">
                <item>
                    <varno><xsl:value-of select="/*/product/OrderingInfo/item[1]"/></partno>
                    <vartitle><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(substring-after(current(),' '),'()',''))"/></vartitle>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried to select the item with the part `/*/product/OrderingInformation/item[1]`
but it always selects the first row of OrderingInfo and from the first product

Comment: Where does the "14205" come from in your output? Should it actually be "12345"?

Comment: oh yeah sorry it should be 12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expression you are looking for is this (so, get the first `item` under the parent of the current node).

```
<varno>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../item[1], ' ')"/>
</varno>
```

Comment: one more question is it possible to add an Element to the XML File with xsl?  I was trying to add the `<varitems></varitems>` with that code :`</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ProductImages">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <varitems></varitems>
    </xsl:template>`(see edit in main code) but it only adds varitems and not the rest of it?